# How can I register an error handler for WebDriverJS in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver

When trying to register an error handler by following the instructions in the documentation, I get an error:

> Register an event listener to be notified whenever there is an
>   unhandled error.
>
> webdriver.promise.Application.
>       getInstance().
>       on('uncaughtException', function(e) {
>         console.error('There was an uncaught exception: ' + e.message);
>       });

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'getInstance' of undefined
```

What is the proper way of registering an error handler?

Answer (score 1):

While searching the WebDriverJS source code I found this:

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/javascript/webdriver/promise.js?r=9d98523583afb01a9c5af7125770081d2a3a2210

```
webdriver.promise.Application = {};
  webdriver.promise.Application.getInstance = function() {
    webdriver.promise.logDeprecation_(
        'webdriver.promise.Application#getInstance()',
        'webdriver.promise.controlFlow()');
    return webdriver.promise.controlFlow();
  };
```

So apparently the proper way is to use:

```
webdriver.promise.controlFlow().on('uncaughtException', function(e) {
        console.error('There was an unhandled exception! ' + e);
    });
```

I've tested this and it works.

(Apparently the version of selenium-webdriver I'm using didn't include this deprecation warning, and instead simply failed.)

Update:

```
  webdriver.promise.logDeprecation_ = function(oldSig, newSig) {
    if (window.console) {
      window.console.log(
          'Using deprecated ' + oldSig + ', use ' + newSig +
          'instead. This will stop working in Selenium 2.31');
    }   };
```

And I was using Selenium 2.32.

Comment: Aha!  `webdriver.promise.controlFlow().on('uncaughtException')` was exactly what I was looking for - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

and [now](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/CHANGES.md#v400-alpha1) that `controlFlow` is deprecated, how i can catch exceptions?